# Como consigo fazer uma animation "spin" no CSS usando o border de uma div?

Tags: css, html5, animação, carregamento, css-border

A animação que quero basicamente é quando eu der hover na div do fingerprint a border fica em loading por 3 segundos (uma animação de tipo progressbar, começando do 0 e chegando ao fim do círculo).

[image: fingerprint css code]

[image: fingerprint border representation]

Comment: Mostre tb o HTML do elemento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar spans junto com o ícone do *fingerprint*. Depois é só trabalhar com um *keyframes* para fazer a animação rotacionando duas spans em sequência: a da direita inicia a animação imediatamente completando o círculo até a metade, enquanto a da esquerda inicia após 1.5 segundo quando a direita iniciou, sendo que as duas animações duram 1.5 segundo, totalizando 3 segundos de animação.

O tempo de duração é ajustável, basta alterar os valores:

```
 // PRIMEIRA ANIMAÇÃO
.fingerprint:hover .progress-right .progress-bar{
   animation: loading 1.5s linear forwards;
                       ↑
                    duração
}

// SEGUNDA ANIMAÇÃO
.progress:hover .progress-left .progress-bar{
   animation: loading 1.5s linear forwards 1.5s;
                       ↑                    ↑
                    duração           tempo de atraso
}
```

Caso queira fazer ajustes no tamanho, você não mexer em nada, exceto as propriedades `width` e `height` dos elementos e no `font-size` do ícone.

**Veja funcionando** (passe o mouse sobre o ícone):

```css
.progress *{
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

.progress{
   width: 130px;
   height: 130px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}
.progress > span{
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.progress .progress-bar{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.progress .progress-left .progress-bar{
    left: 100%;
    border-top-right-radius: 80px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 80px;
    border-left: 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center left;
    transform-origin: center left;
}

.progress .progress-right .progress-bar{
    left: -100%;
    border-top-left-radius: 80px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 80px;
    border-right: 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center right;
    transform-origin: center right;
}

.progress .progress-right{
    right: 0;
}

.progress .progress-bar{
    border-color: #8fa09c;
}

@keyframes loading{
    0%{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100%{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
}


.fingerprint .fas{
   font-size: 100px;
   padding: 15px;
   color: #9e9e9e;
}

.fingerprint{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 130px;
   height: 130px;
   position: relative;
   margin: 10px;
}

.fingerprint:hover .progress-right .progress-bar{
   animation: loading 1.5s linear forwards;
}

.progress:hover .progress-left .progress-bar{
   animation: loading 1.5s linear forwards 1.5s;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="fingerprint">
   <i class="fas fa-fingerprint"></i>
   <div class="progress">
      <span class="progress-left">
         <span class="progress-bar"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="progress-right">
         <span class="progress-bar"></span>
      </span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Aqui tem um exemplo. O ponto principal é animar um *pseudo-elemento* no `:hover` da `div` pai. Assim vc evita de rodar diretamente o pai e por seguinte o filho também. Além disso no `interection-count` do `animation` vc coloca o valor de `3` para girar apenas 3x e depois parar, ou seja, 3 giros em 3 segundos *(cada gira tem 1s e como são 3 giros totaliza 3 segundos, deixei comentários no código)*. Para dar o aspecto de *spin* de *load* basta vc colocar uma das bordas com a cor transparente, eu usei `border-bottom-color: transparent;` para dar esse efeito.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima.

```css
.icon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
}
.icon::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.icon:hover::after {
  animation: gira 1s linear; /* 1s é o tempo da animação de cada giro */
  animation-iteration-count: 3; /* 3 é a quantidade de giros, 3 giros = 3 segundos */
}
@keyframes gira {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
  }
  100% {
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="icon">
  <img src="https://placecage.com/24/24">
</div>
```